# How do I know why NetworkManager failed to initiate the VPN connection?

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, pptp, pppd

I'm running Arch Linux, and recently updated the whole system.

Now I every time I connects to VPN with `nmcli` command, if it fails, I couldn't figure out the reason:

```
NetworkManager[15967]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
NetworkManager[15967]: <info> VPN connection 'XXX' (Connect) reply received.
NetworkManager[15967]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
NetworkManager[15967]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
NetworkManager[15967]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
NetworkManager[15967]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
NetworkManager[15967]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
NetworkManager[15967]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
NetworkManager[15967]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
```

Prior to the upgrade, I can see error messages from pppd, e.g "You're already logged in bla bla", now every helpful message is gone.

Any ideas? Why is the connection failed?

Comment: Things to try here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingNetworkManager. May need to be adapted for Arch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the used loglevel in your `NetworkManager.conf` file

> [logging]
>          This section controls NetworkManager's logging.  Any  settings  here  are
>          overridden by the --log-level and --log-domains command-line options.
>
> ```
>    level=<level>
>           One of [ERR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG].  The ERR level logs only critical
>           errors.  WARN logs warnings that may reflect operation.  INFO logs
>           various  informational messages that are useful for tracking state
>           and operations.   DEBUG  enables  verbose  logging  for  debugging
>           purposes.   Subsequent  levels  also log all messages from earlier
>           levels; thus setting the log level to INFO  also  logs  error  and
>           warning messages.
> ```

But note this part:

> This section controls NetworkManager's logging.  Any  settings  here  are
>          overridden by the --log-level and --log-domains command-line options.

Answer (score 0):

I did check your log and compare with my successful log, have seen that
your ppp plugin for network-manager fail to be loaded and you need install
networkmanager-pptp package to have it.

Comment: Nope, it's already installed